# How do these queries differ

Tags: scala, slick

I'm starting to learning Slick,

But until now I'm pretty unhappy with it, probably because I'm miss understanding it.

Have a single select query here:

```
   private val getChannelBySecret =
     for {
       secret <- Parameters[String]
       channel <- allQuery if channel.secret === secret  
     } yield channel
```

I would assume this is an ok query. But it doesn't return the records I'm querying for.

This on other hand:

```
Compiled((secret: Column[String]) => allQuery.filter(_.secret === secret))
```

Works perfectly fine.
What is the difference here?

Thanks

Comment: Parameters is a legacy API, Compiled is the new way to express it. Your first query uses Scala's for-comprehension syntax, which Scala behind the scene translates into the second version you wrote. I don't see right now why they would produce something different. They look equivalent. What does the first query produce?

Comment: The first query just doesn't return anything. I didn't delve into what each of these produce as SQL